# Are apple-app-site-association paths relative to root or .well-known?

Tags: ios

Are the paths in the apple-app-site-association file relative to the root or the directory that it's in.  If my file is in the .well-known directory, should my path be ../mypath or just /mypath

Also, does it matter if I'm using teamID or appID if I'm trying to test it in the dev environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The association file should map to the paths in the url, not a folder location. So if `http://www.yoursite.com/mypath` is a path that should redirect to your app, then `/mypath` should be in your apple-app-site-association file.

`http://www.yoursite.com/../mypath` for example wouldn't make sense.